# how to send piechart on server through canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

i want to send my flot piechart on server through canvas . i am able to send but the problem with me is that image is storing blank means black color image only.
  my jquery code is given below:

```
              function sendpie()
                  {                   
                  var canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[1];
                  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                   $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    async:false,
                    url:"/decode.php",
                    data:{img:img},
                    success:function(response){                         
                       alert("response="+response);
                    },
                        error:function(response){
                        alert("error"+response);
                    }                        
                });                    
                }
```

### PHP Code

```
 <?php
  include_once './config.php';
   $img=$_POST['img'];
  function saveImage($base64img){
  define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'sketch/');
  $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64img);
  $data = base64_decode($base64img);    
  $file = UPLOAD_DIR . rand(10,100).'.jpg';
   echo"file value=".$file;  
  file_put_contents($file, $data);
   }
   saveImage($img); 
   ?>
```

### My HTML CODE

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js">  </script>
 <script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
   <body>          
       <div class="flotcontainer1" id="flotcontainer1"></div>  
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email ID of receiver">
        <input onclick="sendpie();" type="submit" value="Send Chart"/>
       </body>   
      </html>
```

### My Pie chart drawing code

```
             $(function () 
                      { 
                        var data = [
                            {label:"data1", data:44},
                            {label:"data2", data:44}
                        ];

                        var options = {
                            series: {
                                pie: {show: true}
                                }                                
                                }; 
                        $.plot($("#flotcontainer1"), data, options);                           
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well know problem, Is in black and white because you are sending in JPG format , only PNG format supports transparency.

So you would like to change your code in the following things :

```
function sendpie()
              {                   
              var canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[1];
              var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
               $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async:false,
                url:"/decode.php",
                data:{img:img},
                success:function(response){                         
                   alert("response="+response);
                },
                    error:function(response){
                    alert("error"+response);
                }                        
            });                    
            }
```

PHP Code

```
 include_once './config.php';
 $img=$_POST['img'];
function saveImage($base64img){
 define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'sketch/');
 $base64img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64img);
 $data = base64_decode($base64img);    
 $file = UPLOAD_DIR . rand(10,100).'.png';
  echo"file value=".$file;  
 file_put_contents($file, $data);
 }
  saveImage($img); 
  ?>
```

Thats all , you could search more in google the next time, this question is already answered in many places